# CONCATENATE and IF Function Issues

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation, formula

I'm trying to take a column of data that contains either course information (with text), or just the number 0, and string together the values that do NOT equal 0 from that column into ONLY one cell on another tab.

Ex:

```
[*COLUMN A*]
COURSE B8001
COURSE B8002
0
0
COURSE B8003
```

^ I want to take this column...
and turn it into this...

Cell 1: `COURSE B8001, COURSE B8002, COURSE B8003` (all under the same column, just in one cell)

I have been using the concatenate and if functions to no avail and am stuck.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Do you have `TEXTJOIN()`?

Comment: Are the `,` really on the end of each one?

Comment: @BruceWayne No I don't have that particular formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner -- nope! sorry was just placing that there to indicate separation. first time user here, not sure about the format on this forum. [edited to remove the ,]

Comment: Show your code, it'll get looked at.  You just read the rows, perform your parsing functions, if they pass validation append it, building one long string to place in only one cell.  Post some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A1:A100<>0,A1:A100,""))
```

Being an array formula it would need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode

---

If you do not have OFFICE 365 Excel then you will need a helper column or vba.

Helper, Put this in B1 and drag the length of the data:

```
=IF(A1<>0,A1&","&B2,B2)
```

And your concatenated statement will appear in B1

vba, Put this in a module attached to the workbook:

```
Function TEXTJOINIFS(rng As Range, delim As String, ParamArray arr() As Variant)
    Dim rngarr As Variant
    rngarr = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value

    Dim condArr() As Boolean
    ReDim condArr(1 To Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Rows.Count) As Boolean


    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        Dim colArr() As Variant
        colArr = Intersect(arr(i), arr(i).Parent.UsedRange).Value
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(colArr, 1) To UBound(colArr, 1)

            If Not condArr(j) Then
                Dim charind As Long
                charind = Application.Max(InStr(arr(i + 1), ">"), InStr(arr(i + 1), "<"), InStr(arr(i + 1), "="))
                Dim opprnd As String
                If charind = 0 Then
                    opprnd = "="
                Else
                    opprnd = Left(arr(i + 1), charind)
                End If
                Dim t As String
                t = """" & colArr(j, 1) & """" & opprnd & """" & Mid(arr(i + 1), charind + 1) & """"
                If Not Application.Evaluate(t) Then condArr(j) = True
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = LBound(rngarr, 1) To UBound(rngarr, 1)
        If Not condArr(i) Then
            TEXTJOINIFS = TEXTJOINIFS & rngarr(i, 1) & delim
        End If
    Next i

    TEXTJOINIFS = Left(TEXTJOINIFS, Len(TEXTJOINIFS) - Len(delim))

End Function
```

Then call it like SUMIFS:

```
=TEXTJOINIFS(A:A,",",A:A,"<>0")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that -- can you go in depth on what you mean by helper column? I would have to set that up before using the formula: =IF(A1<>0,A1&","&B2,B2)?